# Oracle 11g DB-Link connection stays open even after re-creating database link

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, connection, dblink

I have problem with Oracle DB-Link connection (Oracle 11g). Let us consider the following situation:

1. We are connected to the database DATABASE_A with user USER1,
2. We are created new private database link to DATABASE_B, username for connecion: USER2

```sql
CREATE DATABASE LINK "CHECK_CONNECTION"
CONNECT TO USER2
IDENTIFIED BY "password1"
USING 'DATABASE_B';
```

3. Test connection failed - password or username is incorrect

```sql
SELECT * FROM DUAL@CHECK_CONNECTION

Error at line 1
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

4. We are changing password:

```sql
DROP DATABASE LINK CHECK_CONNECTION

CREATE DATABASE LINK "CHECK_CONNECTION"
CONNECT TO USER2
IDENTIFIED BY "password2"
USING 'DATABASE_B';
```

5. The connection test was successful

```sql
SELECT * FROM DUAL@CHECK_CONNECTION

DUMMY
-----
X   
1 row selected.
```

6. We are changing password again, to the older one:

```sql
DROP DATABASE LINK CHECK_CONNECTION

CREATE DATABASE LINK "CHECK_CONNECTION"
CONNECT TO USER2
IDENTIFIED BY "password1"
USING 'DATABASE_B';
```

7. Connection still was correct, in spite of the wrong password:

```sql
SELECT * FROM DUAL@CHECK_CONNECTION

DUMMY
-----
X   
1 row selected.
```

8. Only creating new DB-Link with the changed name is detecting the incorrect connection.

```sql
CREATE DATABASE LINK "CHECK_CONNECTION_2"
CONNECT TO USER2
IDENTIFIED BY "password1"
USING 'DATABASE_B';

SELECT * FROM DUAL@CHECK_CONNECTION_2

Error at line 1
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Any idea why is the connection correct in spite of the wrong password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual on the command [alter session close database link](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_2015.htm#SQLRF00901):

> When you issue a statement that uses a database link, Oracle Database
>   creates a session for you on the remote database using that link. The
>   connection remains open until you end your local session...

It's useful that Oracle does not re-connect every time a database link is used.  But it does seem like a minor bug to keep the connection alive even when the database link is changed.  I've verified that this still happens in 12c.

It shouldn't be a big deal because database links should remain fairly static.  Just like the way an application should not re-connect to the database for each query, database sessions should not be changing links frequently.

A lot of weird things happen over database links.  Keep your remote process as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the plan for the calls. It is possible that for the first time, the value was fetched from the database but when it was called for the second time, it was read from the cache. Take small example:

```
SQL> set autotrace traceonly;
SQL> select * from dual;


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 272002086

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          1  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          3  consistent gets
          2  physical reads
          0  redo size
        522  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        523  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          1  rows processed

SQL> select * from dual;


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 272002086

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          3  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        522  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        523  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          1  rows processed

SQL>
```

Its obvious from the trace that during the first call there were 2 physical reads. But when the same statement was called again, there was 0 physical read, that means the result was read from the cache.

In you case, although the definition of db link was changes but the basic sql remained the same and hence a cache hit took place.

Answer (score 0):

@Jon Heller

Your answer was helpful - alter session works, if will be used in step 6, between drop and create proper database link. It doesn't works if will be used after drop improper database link - simply because the connection wasn't created.

However you signalled me, that perhaps my concept of solving my problem had been incorrect.

> It shouldn't be a big deal because database links should remain fairly
>   static. Just like the way an application should not re-connect to the
>   database for each query, database sessions should not be changing
>   links frequently.

I wanted from the level USER1 verify the connection with the other database, using PL/SQL procedure.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE USER1.CHECK_CONNECTION_PROC (
   P_ID         IN     NUMBER,
   P_USERNAME   IN     VARCHAR2,
   P_PASSWORD   IN     VARCHAR2,
   P_DATABASE   IN     VARCHAR2,
   P_RESULT        OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
   M_DBLINK_NAME   VARCHAR2 (100) DEFAULT 'CHECK_CONNECTION';
   M_IS_EXISTS     NUMBER;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
         'CREATE DATABASE LINK "'
      || M_DBLINK_NAME
      || '" CONNECT TO '
      || P_USERNAME
      || ' IDENTIFIED BY "'
      || P_PASSWORD
      || '" USING '''
      || P_DATABASE
      || '''';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DUAL@' || M_DBLINK_NAME;

   P_RESULT := 'PASSED';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP DATABASE LINK ' || M_DBLINK_NAME;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN LOGIN_DENIED
   THEN
      P_RESULT := 'LOGIN_DENIED';

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP DATABASE LINK ' || M_DBLINK_NAME;
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      P_RESULT := SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 200);

      SELECT SIGN (COUNT (*))
        INTO M_IS_EXISTS
        FROM ALL_DB_LINKS
       WHERE DB_LINK = M_DBLINK_NAME;

      IF M_IS_EXISTS = 1
      THEN
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP DATABASE LINK ' || M_DBLINK_NAME;
      END IF;
END CHECK_CONNECTION_PROC;

DECLARE
   M_RESULT   VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TEMPORARY_TABLE';

   INSERT ALL
     INTO TEMPORARY_TABLE (NUMERIC_VALUE1,
                           VARCHAR_VALUE1,
                           VARCHAR_VALUE2,
                           VARCHAR_VALUE3)
   VALUES (1,
           'USER2',
           'password2',
           'DATABASE_B')
     INTO TEMPORARY_TABLE (NUMERIC_VALUE1,
                           VARCHAR_VALUE1,
                           VARCHAR_VALUE2,
                           VARCHAR_VALUE3)
   VALUES (2,
           'USER3',
           'password3',
           'DATABASE_C')
     INTO TEMPORARY_TABLE (NUMERIC_VALUE1,
                           VARCHAR_VALUE1,
                           VARCHAR_VALUE2,
                           VARCHAR_VALUE3)
   VALUES (3,
           'USER4',
           'password4',
           'DATABASE_D')
      SELECT * FROM DUAL;

   FOR CNT IN (  SELECT TMP.NUMERIC_VALUE1 ID,
                        TMP.VARCHAR_VALUE1 USERNAME,
                        TMP.VARCHAR_VALUE2 PASSWORD,
                        TMP.VARCHAR_VALUE3 DATABASE
                   FROM TEMPORARY_TABLE TMP
               ORDER BY 1)
   LOOP
      CHECK_CONNECTION_PROC (CNT.ID,
                             CNT.USERNAME,
                             CNT.PASSWORD,
                             CNT.DATABASE,
                             M_RESULT);

      UPDATE TEMPORARY_TABLE
         SET VARCHAR_VALUE4 = M_RESULT
       WHERE NUMERIC_VALUE1 = CNT.ID;
   END LOOP;
END;

SELECT TMP.NUMERIC_VALUE1 ID,
       TMP.VARCHAR_VALUE1 USERNAME,
       TMP.VARCHAR_VALUE2 PASSWORD,
       TMP.VARCHAR_VALUE3 DATABASE,
       TMP.VARCHAR_VALUE4 RESULT
  FROM TEMPORARY_TABLE TMP;

ID  USERNAME    PASSWORD     DATABASE     RESULT    
---------------------------------------------------
1   USER2       password2    DATABASE_B   PASSED
2   USER3       password3    DATABASE_C   PASSED
3   USER4       password4    DATABASE_D   PASSED

3 rows selected.
```

As for now I didn't find other remedy to verify the correctness of the username and password to other database into other way, than creating temporary DB-Link.

Comment: Your approach makes a lot of sense.  Normally re-connecting to a database frequently is an anti-pattern, but you have a good reason to do so.  One potential issue with this approach is that passwords may be exposed in clear text.  There are a few ways to help reduce that problem.  You can call `sys.dbms_shared_pool.purge` to remove the PL/SQL and bind variable password value from the shared pool (e.g. from V$SQL and some bind data dictionary views).  Or you can replace the password with the password hash, and use `identified by values '[password hash]'`.

Comment: Database links use a separate kind of password hash, stored in `select passwordx from sys.ku$_dblink_view`.  Depending on how these user passwords get set, there's probably some way to automatically create a database link with the new password - maybe through the password verification function or a trigger?  This can get complicated but there's usually a way to completely remove clear text passwords